When installing Ubuntu for the first time, I did not opt in to Bluetooth in the "options" selection, how can I install Bluetooth
When first installing JJ Ubuntu, I did not opt in to Bluetooth.  My mistake... I have searched and tried to install Bluetooth from the terminal, but it does not install.  I am on the latest update of Noble, original install is/was Jammy Jellyfish.

What's "JJ Ubuntu"? What did you try in the terminal? What was the exact command? And how did it not work? Any errors? How are you testing to see if it worked? What is your hardware? Please [edit] your question and give us more details.
